# joint query with two tables

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, join

I have **tradefile** table as follows:

```
ID          int
TradeNo     nvarchar(50)    
Scrip_Code  nvarchar(50)    
Inst_Type   nvarchar(50)    
Expirydate  datetime    
Buy_Sell    float   
Trade_Qty   float   
Market_Rate float   
Party_Code  nvarchar(50)    
Sauda_Date  nvarchar(50)
```

**FOClosing** table as:

```
Cl_Rate         money   
Expirydate      datetime
Trade_Date     datetime
Inst_Type      varchar(6)
Symbol     varchar(12)
```

I am just firing following query to get data from tradefile table:

```
SELECT   Scrip_Code,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyRate, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyAmount,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellRate,(CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)>SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) THEN 'BF' ELSE 'BT' END ) as TradeType, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellAmount, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) as NETQTY,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)as NetAmt,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) as PNLAmt FROM tradeFile where Inst_Type='FUTIDX' OR Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'1 Mar 2013') and convert(datetime,'1 Apr 2013') group by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date
```

I just wanted to attach cl_Rate[Closing rate ] to it.

closingrate is checked as  `tradeFile.ExpiryDate=flclosing.expirydate` and `tradefile.saudadate=foclosing.tradedate` and `Inst_Type='FUTURISTIK'`

I have these conditions but when i try to attach those on above query it does not works because group by is already used.

Can any one help me to attach cl_rate column with above conditions in above query???

**EDIT:**

```
try
            {

                con.Open();
                float closingRate = 0;
                DateTime dtExpDate=DateTime.Now.Date;

                da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT   ExpiryDate,Scrip_Code,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyRate, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyAmount,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellRate,(CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)>SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) THEN 'BF' ELSE 'BT' END ) as TradeType, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellAmount, SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) as NETQTY,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)as NetAmt,SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 2 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN Buy_sell = 1 THEN Trade_Qty * Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) as PNLAmt FROM tradeFile where Inst_Type='FUTIDX' OR Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') group by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                 da.Fill(ds);

                 for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                 {
                     dtExpDate = DateTime.Parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());
                     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString() == "BF")
                     {

                         daClRate = new SqlDataAdapter("select cl_rate,ExpiryDate,symbol from foClosing where Symbol='" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString() + "' and convert(datetime,convert(varchar(11),ExpiryDate))= '" + dtExpDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and trade_date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "')  order by trade_date ", con);
                         dsClRate = new DataSet();
                         daClRate.Fill(dsClRate);
                         for (int j = 0; j < dsClRate.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                         {
                             closingRate = float.Parse(dsClRate.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString());
                         }

                     }
                     else
                     {
                     }
                 }
```

In this way i am taking closing value via different query.

Comment: What do you mean by attach.. Are you trying to modify query in your programming language?? If so which language

Comment: c# windows application.

Comment: is it possible to share the code related to the function where this query is being executed

Comment: @AjoKoshy please go through the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your main query to

> SELECT   tf.ExpiryDate,tf.Scrip_Code,fc.cl_rate, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS BuyQty, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyRate, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS BuyAmount,SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) AS SellQty, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellRate,(CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)>SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) THEN 'BF' ELSE 'BT' END ) as TradeType, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) AS SellAmount, SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty ELSE 0 END) as NETQTY,SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)as NetAmt,SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 2 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END)-SUM(CASE WHEN tf.Buy_sell = 1 THEN tf.Trade_Qty * tf.Market_Rate ELSE 0 END) as PNLAmt FROM tradeFile tf,foClosing fc where tf.Inst_Type='FUTIDX' OR tf.Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and tf.Sauda_Date between convert(datetime,'" + dtpForDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') and convert(datetime,convert(varchar(11),fc.ExpiryDate))= '" + dtExpDate.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and convert(datetime,'" + dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString() + "') and fc.symbol = tf.Scrip_Code and fc.Inst_Type='FUTSTK' and fc.trade_date=tf.sauda_date and fc.ExpiryDate = tf.ExpiryDate group by Scrip_Code,ExpiryDate,sauda_date

What your previous question didnt make clear was the foreign key.. You are matching the `forClosing.Symbol` with `tradeFile.Scrip_Code`. This was the missing piece.